# .NET Web API getting Unable to connect to any of the specified MySQL Docker Container hosts with EF Core

Tags: c#, docker-compose, entity-framework-core, asp.net-core-webapi

My goal is to create an Web Api .Net in a container accessing my MySql database in another docker container,  with entity framework core.

Here is the appsettings.json file with the connection string:

```
{
  "Logging": {
    "LogLevel": {
      "Default": "Information",
      "Microsoft.AspNetCore": "Warning"
    }
  },
  "AllowedHosts": "*",
  "ConnectionStrings": {
    "MySqlConnection": "Server=mysql-container;port=3306;User ID=mysqlDbUser;Password=mysqlDbPass#;Database=UserAPI"
  }
}
```

My DockerCompose.yml:

```
version: '3.4'

services:
  userapi:
    image: ${DOCKER_REGISTRY-}userapi
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: UserAPI/Dockerfile

  database:
    image: mysql:latest
    container_name: mysql-container
    ports:
      - "3306:3306"
    expose: 
      - 3306
    volumes:
      - db-volume:/var/lib/mysqll
    restart: always
    environment: 
      MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: root
      MYSQL_USER: mysqlDbUser
      MYSQL_PASSWORD: mysqlDbPass#
      MYSQL_DATABASE: UserAPI
volumes:
  db-volume:
```

My program class with MySQL Pomelo to add the UserContext with MySql:

```
builder.Services.AddDbContext<UserContext>(options => 
    options.UseMySql(
        builder.Configuration.GetConnectionString("MySqlConnection"), 
        ServerVersion.AutoDetect(builder.Configuration.GetConnectionString("MySqlConnection"))));
```

When the statup project is the docker-compose, it lauches an error to generate migration and update-database commands. So, i switch to UserAPI to my startup project, create the migration successfully, but when i run the database-update, it generates the error

`MySqlConnector.MySqlException (0x80004005): Unable to connect to any of the specified MySQL hosts.`
`Unable to connect to any of the specified MySQL hosts.`

My goal is to run my web api in a container and my mysql in another, with the web api acessing the container with database.

Answer (score 0):

ConnectionString cannot recognize "container_name: mysql-container". You will need to crate a network .let both usrpai and mysql join the network. and assign the mysql contianer a network alias name: "mysql-container". Then you could use the connectionstring as like "Server=mysql-container;port=...." You could try like this

```
version: '3.4'

services:
  network:
    custom_network:
      driver: bridge
  userapi:
    image: ${DOCKER_REGISTRY-}userapi
    networks:
      custom_network:
      aliases:
        - usrapi
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: UserAPI/Dockerfile

  database:
    image: mysql:latest
    networks:
      custom_network:
      aliases:
        - mysql-container
    ports:
      - "3306:3306"
    expose: 
      - 3306
    volumes:
      - db-volume:/var/lib/mysqll
    restart: always
    environment: 
      MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: root
      MYSQL_USER: mysqlDbUser
      MYSQL_PASSWORD: mysqlDbPass#
      MYSQL_DATABASE: UserAPI
volumes:
  db-volume:
```